# Error when installing python pyminizip module and zlib.dll

Tags: python, system, zlib

I am trying to install the python pyminizip module on my PC but i have the fallowing error :

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install pyminizip
Collecting pyminizip
  Using cached pyminizip-0.2.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyminizip
  Running setup.py install for pyminizip ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools
, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\andrei~1.gug\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-mb
aaft\\pyminizip\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.re
ad().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" inst
all --record c:\users\andrei~1.gug\appdata\local\temp\pip-9hqnfh-record\install-
record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyminizip' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src
    C:\Users\Andrei-Cristian.GUGI\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual
 C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Isrc -Ic
:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tcsrc/py_minizip.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\
Release\src/py_minizip.obj
    py_minizip.c
    c:\users\andrei-cristian.gugi\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-mbaaft\pyminizip\
src\zip.h(43) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such f
ile or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\Andrei-Cristian.GUGI\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\C
ommon\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit
status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\
\users\\andrei~1.gug\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-mbaaft\\pyminizip\\setup.p
y';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n
');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\an
drei~1.gug\appdata\local\temp\pip-9hqnfh-record\install-record.txt --single-vers
ion-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\andrei~1.
gug\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-mbaaft\pyminizip\
```

I also tried to install the zlib.dll -> copied from the internet to the C:\Windows\SysWOW64 --> same result

Can someone please help me with this toppic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of already asked question. Check here
[Already asked question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161398/cant-compile-libpng-1-6-on-windows-via-cmake-cannot-open-include-file-zlib-h)

Comment: I have read all the comments in that topic but none work on my side :'(

Answer (score 1):

First get a copy of pyminizip from pypi and **zlib** source (http://zlib.net/zlib1211.zip)
A few things you need to do after that:

1. compile the `zlibvc` solution file using Visual Studio (Here's how: http://www.tannerhelland.com/5076/compile-zlib-winapi-wapi-stdcall/) - make sure you compile for the right platform (x86/x64!!)
2. copy the created '`zlibstat.lib`' from `ZLibStatRelease` subfolder into the python package install folder (next to setup.py) and rename it to '`zlib.lib`'
3. copy all the zlib source files (except `makefile`) from the zlib folder into the python package src subfolder, including the win32 subfolder

Now you should be good to go installing using 'python setup.py install'